# How to put a CardView attribute in a style?

Tags: android, android-cardview

I have:

in a file `build.gradle` (dependencies)

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
}
```

in a file `styles.xml` (styles definition)

```
<resources
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <style name="CardViewStyle">
        <item name="android:layout_margin">5dip</item>
        <item name="card_view:cardCornerRadius">4dp</item>
        <item name="card_view:cardElevation">4dp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

But compiler complains:

**Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'card_view:cardCornerRadius'.**

How do I add some cardView attributes in a style?

Comment: Does my answer work as expected?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Set `parent` attribute to `CardView`.
You don't even have to add `xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`.

Working snippet of code:

```
<style name="CardViewStyle" parent="CardView">
     <item name="cardCornerRadius">4dp</item>
     <item name="cardElevation">4dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: VsMax make sure you're doing 

<item name="cardCornerRadius">4dp</item>

not

<item name="card_view:cardCornerRadius">4dp</item>

Answer (score 19):

To add to mklimek's answer, you do not even need to add the parent="CardView"

Just avoid the cardView: prefix

So instead of

```
    <item name="cardView:cardElevation">5dp</item>
```

just use

```
    <item name="cardElevation">5dp</item>
```

So my complete style code for this is:

```
<style name="categoriesCardViewButtons">
    <item name="android:layout_width">80dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">10dp</item>
    <item name="cardCornerRadius">8dp</item>
    <item name="cardElevation">5dp</item>
    <item name="cardBackgroundColor">@color/grey_ultra_light</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/l1LayoutPaddingB</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 5):

This error can occur if you do not have CardView in your gradle dependencies (in Android Studio) *for the module containing your style* (even though you have the dependency in the module where you use the card view). In that case, simply add

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1'
```

(or another version) to `build.gradle` for the module containing themes.xml or styles.xml.

Then, you do not need to set a parent on your style, nor do you need a namespace prefix, but can follow the example in tsik's answer, so all you need is

```
<style name="myStyle">
    <item name="cardCornerRadius">8dp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

This code work well

```
<style name="MyCardView" parent="CardView">
    <item name="cardUseCompatPadding">true</item>
    <item name="cardCornerRadius">@dimen/hei_standard_8dp</item>
    <item name="cardBackgroundColor">@color/bg_item_list_alphabet</item>
</style>
```

Note: parent ="CardView"