# How to add CardView attributes to app theme?

Tags: android, android-cardview

My question is similar to "[How to put a CardView attribute in a style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27341832/how-to-put-a-cardview-attribute-in-a-style)", but I need to go deeper.

I'm using AppCompat theme, and my styles looks like

```
style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/toolbar_color</item>
    <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/CustomListView</item>
</style>
```

and I create separate style for CardView

```
<style name="CustomCardView" parent="CardView">
    <item name="cardBackgroundColor">@color/card_background</item>
    <item name="cardCornerRadius">@dimen/card_corner</item>
</style>
```

Can I attach it to main style?

Comment: Please check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36005912/2826147).

Answer (score 5):

```
public View(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)
```

> @param *defStyleAttr* An attribute in the current theme that contains a
>                reference to a style resource that supplies default values for
>                the view. Can be 0 to not look for defaults.

So you have to do

**attrs.xml**

```
<attr name="myCardViewStyle"/>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="myCardViewStyle">@style/CustomCardView</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomCardView" parent="CardView">
    <item name="cardBackgroundColor">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item>
</style>
```

**MyCardView.java**

```
public MyCardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, R.attr.myCardViewStyle);
}

public MyCardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}
```

That's it.

Comment: Could you please explain where to reference the MyCardView class in Code or Style?

Comment: @SenthilkumarS Just use it in your layout files just like any other view. `<com.myapplicationpackage.views.custom.MyCardView> ...</com.myapplicationpackage.views.custom.MyCardView>`