# Attach custom CardView style to theme

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-cardview

In my app, I have two themes (light and dark), and I want all of my `CardView`s to change their background color depending on which theme is selected.

What I **don't** want is:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    style="@style/CardView.MyBlue"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
```

The above code is not dynamic. I need my two styles to automatically be applied depending on if a light or a dark theme is selected.

---

What I have right now doesn't work:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Light" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
   ...
   <item name="cardViewStyle">@style/CardViewStyle.Light</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.Dark" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
   ...
   <item name="cardViewStyle">@style/CardViewStyle.Dark</item>
</style>

<style name="CardViewStyle.Light" parent="CardView">
    <item name="cardBackgroundColor">@color/cardview_dark_background</item>
</style>

<style name="CardViewStyle.Dark" parent="CardView">
        <item name="cardBackgroundColor">@color/cardview_light_background</item>
</style>
```

I read somewhere that you can define a `styleable.xml` file in `/res/values/` to key the word `cardViewStyle`, so I did that:

`styleable.xml:`

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="AppTheme">
        <attr name="cardViewStyle" format="reference" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

### Update

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29914671/how-to-add-cardview-attributes-to-app-theme) with no answer either.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <attr format="reference" name="cardStyle"/>

    <style name="Light" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="cardStyle">@style/CardView.Light</item>
        ...
    </style>

    <style name="Dark" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="cardStyle">@style/CardView.Dark</item>
        ...
    </style>
</resources>
```

Then in your other xml to use the new attribute, you would use it like this

```
style="?attr/cardStyle"
```

Comment: works like a charm! Make sure you put CardView.Light in your light style so that it picks it up when you switch back and forth

Answer (score 10):

To show more detail about how to implement David Park's solution...

Put this in attrs.xml:

```
<declare-styleable name = "cardStyle">
     <attr name="cardStyle" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>

<style name="Light" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="cardStyle">@style/CardView.Light</item>
</style>

<style name="Dark" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="cardStyle">@style/CardView.Dark</item>
</style>
```

Then, add cardStyle to your theme in styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppThemeLight" parent="AppTheme.Base"/>
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="cardStyle">@style/CardView.Light</item>
</style>

<style name="AppThemeDark" parent="AppTheme.Base.Dark"/>
<style name="AppTheme.Base.Dark" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="cardStyle">@style/CardView.Dark</item>
</style>
```

Then use the attr wherever you have a CardView:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/header_card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
    style="?attr/cardStyle">

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/header_title"

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Usefull, but what about an attribute that automatically stylish all CardViews without define the "style" for each View? Something like radioButtonStyle for radio button. I gave a look to R.Attr of CardView but it seems not present. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/cardview/R.attr.html

Comment: Is the `<declare-styleable/>` really necessary or is putting `<attr format="reference" name="cardStyle"/>` in `styles.xml` under `<resources/>` a shorthand?

Comment: @ARLabs `CardView` passes 0 as `defStyleAttr` so the only way I see is to subclass it and pass our custom attribute as a default. See my answer for details.

Comment: @ARLabs trying to achieve the same thing.  suspect this may not be possible because CardView is in a library outside the core Android SDK

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to add `style="?cardViewStyle"` to every `CardView` in your layouts, you can subclass `CardView` and set the style attribute in the constructor (too bad they didn't do that in the support library). Then use that subclass in the XML, instead of `CardView`.

```java
package com.example.widget;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import com.example.R;

/**
 * {@link CardView} subclass that allows theme'ing through
 * the {@link R.attr#cardViewStyle} attribute.
 * <p>
 * The attribute needs to be defined, for example in <code>attrs.xml</code> as:
 * <pre>
 *   &lt;attr format="reference" name="cardViewStyle"/&gt;
 * </pre>
 * <p>
 * You'll need to set that attribute in your theme, as usual:
 * <pre>
 *   &lt;item name="cardViewStyle"&gt;@style/CardView.MyStyle&lt;/item&gt;
 * </pre>
 * And define the style itself, for example:
 * <pre>
 *   &lt;style name="CardView.MyStyle" parent="CardView.Light"&gt;
 *     &lt;item name="cardCornerRadius"&gt;0dp&lt;/item&gt;
 *   &lt;/style&gt;
 * </pre>
 */
public class StylishCardView extends CardView {
  public StylishCardView(@NonNull Context context) {
    this(context, null);
  }

  public StylishCardView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, R.attr.cardViewStyle);
  }

  public StylishCardView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
  }
}
```

The attribute `cardViewStyle` needs to be defined, for example in `attrs.xml` as:

```
<attr format="reference" name="cardViewStyle"/>
```

You'll need to set that attribute in your theme, as usual:

```
<item name="cardViewStyle">@style/CardView.MyStyle</item>
```

And define the style itself, for example:

```
<style name="CardView.MyStyle" parent="CardView.Light">
    <item name="cardCornerRadius">0dp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I've been able to come up with is to manually hold a constant variable for the card color should be after every theme change. Then, I get every instance of a card that is in my application and set its color to that constant variable.

So, I have a BaseActivity from which all of my activities extend from. In it, I handle the card color change in addition to handling the theme. See below:

`BaseActivity.java`:

```
public class BaseActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private static final int DEFAULT_THEME_ID = R.style.AppTheme_Dark;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        int theme_id =
                PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).getInt("THEME_ID", DEFAULT_THEME_ID);
        setTheme(theme_id);

        int card_color;
        if (theme_id == DEFAULT_THEME_ID){
            card_color = R.color.cv_dark;
        } else{
            card_color = R.color.cv_light;
        }
        Constants.CARD_COLOR = card_color;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

This is definitely not the best way to do this, but until someone else can find a better way to implement styling, this is all I can think of.