# How to set CardView attributes in style.xml file in android

Tags: android, xml, android-styles, android-cardview

I have set a style for my `CardView` in `style.xml` file
but its giving me error on compile time for `app:cardCornerRadius`, `app:cardElevation`, app:cardPreventCornerOverlap and `app:contentPadding` attributes. What is the correct way to set style for a `CardView` in Android?

Below is some of my code:

```
<style name="CardViewStyle" parent="CardView">
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">@dimen/cardMarginVertical</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">@dimen/cardMarginVertical</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">@dimen/cardMarginHorizontal</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">@dimen/cardMarginHorizontal</item>
    <item name="app:cardCornerRadius">2dp</item>
    <item name="app:cardElevation">2dp</item>
    <item name="app:cardPreventCornerOverlap">false</item>
    <item name="app:contentPadding">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: May I see some Logs?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Set parent attribute to CardView.
You don't even have to add

- app: qualifier
- xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto". is not required

Working snippet of code:

```
<style name="CardViewStyle" parent="CardView">
 <item name="cardCornerRadius">4dp</item>
 <item name="cardElevation">4dp</item>
</style>
```

- similar ques
- [How to put a CardView attribute in a style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27341832/how-to-put-a-cardview-attribute-in-a-style)

Comment: you can also declare without parent as <style name="CardViewStyle">
 <item name="cardCornerRadius">4dp</item>
 <item name="cardElevation">4dp</item>
</style>

Comment: For me, this did not work for API level 16. I had to put it in the main theme itself