# CardView custom style attributes

Tags: android, xml, android-cardview, android-styles, cardview

I read many other question about this stuff like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27341832/how-to-put-a-cardview-attribute-in-a-style) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31221911/how-to-set-cardview-attributes-in-style-xml-file-in-android) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30417847/attach-custom-cardview-style-to-theme) but no one work for me.

I need to create a custom style form CardView. This is my code:

style.xml

```
<resources >    
 ...
    <style name="CardViewStyle" parent="CardView">
        <item name="app:cardBackgroundColor">#d9edf7</item>
    </style>    
</resources>
```

my_card.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/CardViewStyle">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txvId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txvDatetime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

In my app gradle file

```
compileSdkVersion 26
minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 26
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
```

Unlikely this do not work for me. Nothing happens, but I do not find the problem.
If I do not use the custom style and do directly :

my_card.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#d9edf7" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txvId"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txvDatetime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

It works fine. But I need to use a custom style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't set theme in cardview instead of style

change this

```
android:theme="@style/CardViewStyle"
```

To

```
style="@style/CardViewStyle"
```

and it's work.

Answer (score -1):

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="6dp"
    tools:context="in.a.a.a.a">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_sylb"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="8sp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Coming soon"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:typeface="serif" />


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</ScrollView>
```

Comment: i put cardview inside scrollView